# How to stage repository with multiple folders

Tags: node.js, git, github, create-react-app

I have a multifolder project that I want to push to a remote repository. It's a pretty standard issue structure with a root folder that contains a client and a server. For some reason when I want to stage this, server is the only file acknowledged and committed. When it's pushed to GitHub, the repository shows both client and server folders, but the server(which I built from scratch) is the only one that contains files and folders. The client folder(which is built from create-react-app) is an empty folder.

```
Root_
     |
      client(create-react-app client)_
     |                               _.gitignore
     |                               _package.json
     |
      server_
            _.gitignore
            _package.json
```

In other projects I've built everything from scratch and there's been no problem, so I figure it has something to do with the existence of two .gitignore files, two package.json files, or the create-react-app itself. I've searched for answers here and in git's documentation. I attempted to use submodules and nothing I've found so far seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing wrong with having multiple gitIgnore files as long as it's not ignoring the files you want to version. What happens when you: (1) save your project first and clean by deleting your local repo? (2) clone again (3) add and commit the missing files (client) (4) `git status` to make sure you see #3 succeeded (5) and finally push to your remote repo. Please show some more necessary code or response messages.

Comment: Thank you Tyro. In following your steps I realized what happened. Both the client and server folders had been initialized for their own repositories. After deleting both of those with `rm -rf .git` , and then doing the same with the root folder, everything worked just fine.